Openvpn and docker (subnet issue?)
I have strictly followed the workflow to set up my container (among other also running) but I can't connect from a client (wherever it is located on my smartphone or PC). The serveur pings well and port 1194/udp is well opened:
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             172.20.0.4           udp dpt:openvpn
My docker conf:
version: '2'
networks:
  default:
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.20.0.0/16

  openvpn:
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
    container_name: openvpn
    restart: always
    image: kylemanna/openvpn
    restart: always
    networks:
      - default
    ports:
      - "1194:1194/udp"
    volumes:
      - "/home/docker/volumes/openvpn/conf:/etc/openvpn"
      - "/home/docker/volumes/openvpn/tmp:/tmp"

I suspect the subnet to be an issue, but I didn't dare touching the openvpn.conf:
server 192.168.255.0 255.255.255.0
verb 3
key /etc/openvpn/pki/private/vpn1.lutix.org.key
ca /etc/openvpn/pki/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/pki/issued/vpn1.lutix.org.crt
dh /etc/openvpn/pki/dh.pem
tls-auth /etc/openvpn/pki/ta.key
key-direction 0
keepalive 10 60
persist-key
persist-tun

proto udp
# Rely on Docker to do port mapping, internally always 1194
port 1194
dev tun0
status /tmp/openvpn-status.log

user nobody
group nogroup
comp-lzo no

### Route Configurations Below
route 192.168.254.0 255.255.255.0

### Push Configurations Below
push "block-outside-dns"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
push "comp-lzo no"

Running the container, I don't feel like there is any issue raised:
openvpn         | Checking IPv6 Forwarding
openvpn         | Sysctl error for disable_ipv6, please run docker with '--sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=0'
openvpn         | Sysctl error for default forwarding, please run docker with '--sysctl net.ipv6.conf.default.forwarding=1'
openvpn         | Sysctl error for all forwarding, please run docker with '--sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1'
openvpn         | Running 'openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/openvpn.conf --client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/ccd --crl-verify /etc/openvpn/crl.pem '
openvpn         | Thu Sep 12 05:02:59 2024 OpenVPN 2.4.9 x86_64-alpine-linux-musl [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Apr 20 2020
openvpn         | Thu Sep 12 05:02:59 2024 library versions: OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020, LZO 2.10
openvpn         | Thu Sep 12 05:02:59 2024 Diffie-Hellman initialized with 2048 bit key
openvpn         | Thu Sep 12 05:02:59 2024 CRL: loaded 1 CRLs from file /etc/openvpn/crl.pem
openvpn         | Thu Sep 12 05:03:00 2024 Outgoing Control Channel Authentication: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
openvpn         | Thu Sep 12 05:03:00 2024 Incoming Control Channel Authentication: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
openvpn         | Thu Sep 12 05:03:00 2024 ROUTE_GATEWAY 172.20.0.1/255.255.0.0 IFACE=eth0 HWADDR=02:42:ac:14:00:04
openvpn         | Thu Sep 12 05:03:00 2024 TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
openvpn         | Thu Sep 12 05:03:00 2024 TUN/TAP TX queue length set to 100
openvpn         | Thu Sep 12 05:03:00 2024 /sbin/ip link set dev tun0 up mtu 1500
openvpn         | Thu Sep 12 05:03:00 2024 /sbin/ip addr add dev tun0 local 192.168.255.1 peer 192.168.255.2
openvpn         | Thu Sep 12 05:03:00 2024 /sbin/ip route add 192.168.254.0/24 via 192.168.255.2
openvpn         | Thu Sep 12 05:03:00 2024 /sbin/ip route add 192.168.255.0/24 via 192.168.255.2
openvpn         | Thu Sep 12 05:03:00 2024 Could not determine IPv4/IPv6 protocol. Using AF_INET
openvpn         | Thu Sep 12 05:03:00 2024 Socket Buffers: R=[212992->212992] S=[212992->212992]
openvpn         | Thu Sep 12 05:03:00 2024 UDPv4 link local (bound): [AF_INET][undef]:1194
openvpn         | Thu Sep 12 05:03:00 2024 UDPv4 link remote: [AF_UNSPEC]
openvpn         | Thu Sep 12 05:03:00 2024 GID set to nogroup
openvpn         | Thu Sep 12 05:03:00 2024 UID set to nobody
openvpn         | Thu Sep 12 05:03:00 2024 MULTI: multi_init called, r=256 v=256
openvpn         | Thu Sep 12 05:03:00 2024 IFCONFIG POOL: base=192.168.255.4 size=62, ipv6=0
openvpn         | Thu Sep 12 05:03:00 2024 Initialization Sequence Completed

what does the client openvpn:
2024-09-12 07:03:57 --cipher is not set. Previous OpenVPN version defaulted to BF-CBC as fallback when cipher negotiation failed in this case. If you need this fallback please add '--data-ciphers-fallback BF-CBC' to your configuration and/or add BF-CBC to --data-ciphers.
2024-09-12 07:03:57 OpenVPN 2.5.9 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Jun 27 2024
2024-09-12 07:03:57 library versions: OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022, LZO 2.10
2024-09-12 07:03:57 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]XXX.XXX.XXX.XX:1194
2024-09-12 07:03:57 UDP link local: (not bound)
2024-09-12 07:03:57 UDP link remote: [AF_INET]XXX.XXX.XXX.XX:1194
2024-09-12 07:04:57 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
2024-09-12 07:04:57 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed


If someone has an idea. I think this is a matter of routes to be added, but I am not skilled enough, so any help would be much appreciated!
How to get more explicit messages?

Questions on Server Fault must be about managing information technology systems in a business environment. Home and end-user computing questions may be asked on Super User,

It looks like you're encountering a TLS handshake failure, which is often due to routing, network, or certificate configuration issues. Since you suspect that the subnet or routes might be an issue, here are a few things you can check:

Check OpenVPN Configuration:
Your OpenVPN server config (server 192.168.255.0 255.255.255.0) is using the 192.168.255.0/24 subnet, while the Docker network is set to 172.20.0.0/16. These two subnets are different, which is fine, but you need to ensure that the VPN traffic is properly routed between them.
Make sure the push routes from the OpenVPN server include any networks you want to route through the VPN. Example:

push "route 172.20.0.0 255.255.0.0"

Also, ensure that your client-side configuration includes remote with the public IP address of your OpenVPN server.

Ensure Firewall Rules are Set Correctly:
Since port 1194/UDP is already open, check if the server's firewall allows traffic to the 192.168.255.0/24 subnet. Example iptables rule:

sudo iptables -I FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -I FORWARD -i eth0 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT


TLS Error:
The client log shows a TLS key negotiation failed. This is typically caused by mismatched or missing keys/certificates. Double-check that:
The client's .ovpn file has the correct keys (CA, cert, key).
Your openvpn.conf refers to the correct paths for the server's keys.
Both the server and client configurations should match in terms of encryption settings (e.g., cipher settings).

Debugging Network Routes:
To see if it's a routing issue, try running traceroute from the client to check if packets reach the OpenVPN server. This will help identify any point where traffic might be dropped.
Enable more verbose logging on both the client and server to gather more information. On the server side, increase the verbosity by modifying the verb value:


verb 4


Check Docker Configuration:
The Docker network and the OpenVPN subnet seem to be separate. Ensure that Docker networking is properly configured to allow communication between the Docker container and the external network, as well as between the container's virtual network and the OpenVPN subnet.

After checking and updating these configurations, restart your OpenVPN server and try connecting again. If the problem persists, let me know what the logs say after these adjustments!
also you can use this docker compose :
version: '2'

services:
  openvpn:
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
    container_name: openvpn
    restart: always
    image: kylemanna/openvpn
    networks:
      default:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.0.4  # Assign a static IP to the OpenVPN container
    ports:
      - "1194:1194/udp"
    volumes:
      - "/home/docker/volumes/openvpn/conf:/etc/openvpn"
      - "/home/docker/volumes/openvpn/tmp:/tmp"
    sysctls:  # Enable IPv6 forwarding and other necessary sysctl settings for OpenVPN
      - net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=0
      - net.ipv6.conf.default.forwarding=1
      - net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1
    environment:
      - "OVPN_SERVER_CN=YOUR_PUBLIC_IP_OR_DOMAIN"  # Replace with your public IP or domain name

networks:
  default:
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.20.0.0/16

mportant Notes:
Static IP for OpenVPN: I added an ipv4_address: 172.20.0.4 to the OpenVPN container. This ensures that the container always gets the same IP, which might help with routing and firewall rules.

sysctls for IPv6: I included sysctls to enable IPv6 forwarding as requested by the logs. You can keep or remove these settings depending on whether you plan to use IPv6.

OVPN_SERVER_CN: Replace YOUR_PUBLIC_IP_OR_DOMAIN with your server's public IP or a domain name. This helps the OpenVPN server identify its CN (Common Name) in the TLS handshake.

openvpn config :
# Ensure your encryption settings are correct
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA256

# Push routes for Docker network and DNS
push "route 172.20.0.0 255.255.0.0"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"

# Compression
comp-lzo no

# Enable TLS Authentication
tls-auth /etc/openvpn/pki/ta.key 0

Final Checklist:
Public IP/Domain: Ensure your OpenVPN server's public IP/domain is properly set in both the client .ovpn file and the server openvpn.conf.
Port Forwarding: Ensure that UDP port 1194 is forwarded on your router if you're running the OpenVPN server behind a NAT.
Firewall: Make sure the host server's firewall allows traffic to tun0 (the VPN interface).
This should help ensure your Docker OpenVPN setup is properly configured. Let me know if you encounter further issues!
